# Excel: How to check if a value that meets the specified criteria exists in a lookup table?

Tags: excel

Just say I have the following data in **Sheet2**:

```
  --+-----+-----+
    :  A  :  B  :
  --+-----+-----+
  1 : abc : 123 :
  --+-----+-----+
  2 : def : 456 :
  --+-----+-----+
  3 : hij : 789 :
  --+-----+-----+
```

Now, from **Sheet1**, I want to search for "def" value in **Sheet2** which has value "456" in its B column. If it is found, then return "exist" value in the current cell of **Sheet1**.

How can I do that? I think, I could be achieved by combining the VLOOKUP and ISNA with another function, but I don't know which one.

Comment: I'd combine IF with VLOOKUP.    Why don't you try it and see rather than asking here?

Comment: Use `countifs` (excel 2007+ only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Countifs`

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,"def",Sheet2!B:B,456),"exists","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MATCH:

```
  =IF(MATCH("def",Sheet2!A:A,0)=MATCH("456",Sheet2!B:B,0),"exists")
```

If a match cannot be found, this formula will return "#N/A". If you wish it to show something else when there is not a match, then wrap the formula in the IFERROR function.

```
  =IFERROR(IF(MATCH("def",Sheet2!A:A,0)=MATCH("456",Sheet2!B:B,0),"exists"),"value_to_return")
```